# How to turn this datetime format without any other characters?

Tags: python-3.x

I want my datetime format to be like this "20210613172123" from this "2021-06-13 17:21:23.039823". Is this possible in python?

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now)
```

Comment: `print(now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))`, check [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for how to format time to string you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what you need to do :

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
formatted_time_expression = f'{now.year}{now.month}{now.day}{now.hour}{now.minute}{now.second}{now.microsecond}'
print(formatted_time_expression)
```

Comment: I try your code but it gives me an error:AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'millisecond'

Comment: beacuse I changed millisecond to microsecond

Comment: @SplendidArt, it was a little mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

Use strftime to convert datetime object to the required string format.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now)
print(now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
```

## datetime to timestamp

```
from datetime import datetime

# current date and time
now = datetime.now()

timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print("timestamp =", timestamp)
```

## timestamp to datetime

```
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print("dt_object =", dt_object)
print("type(dt_object) =", type(dt_object))
```